# How can you pre-auth a subscription payment with stripe (after the first payment)

Tags: stripe-payments

I know I can pre-auth a stripe subscription with a trial period.  I want to pre-auth the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, nth subscription payment.  The info we are sending out is time critical and if their subscription lapses due to NSF or something else, it would be nice for them if they could rectify the problem BEFORE it lapses.

There is a pending invoice you can get for a subscription, and you can create a payment intent with an invoice ID so that when the invoice is paid, the payment intent (that captured the money) will be used to collect the money.  BUT the pending invoice doesn't have an ID until one or 2 hours before they try to collect the money which is 3-4 days too late.

Has anyone figured out how to pre-auth subscription payments other than the first one?

Is there a subscription engine I could use (with stripe/paypal/venmo) that would mean I could quit using the deficient stripe subscription system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscription invoices don't exist until the renewal of the billing cycle, and the underlying payment intent is created by the invoice. It's not supported to "pre-auth" subscription payments. Instead, you need to [handle payment failures](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures) when those occur, optionally by [letting Stripe handle that for you](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#settings).

If you want to have successful payment in advance of some time-sensitive event, then I'd suggest one of two alternatives:

1. [Shift your billing cycle](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#changing) to invoice 3-4 days ahead of what you have set now, allowing you time to recover from payment failures before the delivery timing.
2. Alternatively you would implement your own recurring payments using [saved payment details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method). You would similarly want to authorize the payment ahead of time to allow for recovery. You could optionally use manual capture to [defer capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later#authorize-only) until the time of delivery.

Comment: #1 Seemed like just the thing, but in that case it looks like I need to do proration for the current period and it is likely to sow all kinds of confusion for the people that are subscribing.

Comment: #2 Is what I was thinking is more likely what I'll have to do and while that moves all the complexity out of stripe and onto my plate, it also means I could open up to accepting Venmo, Paypal, and Cashapp, all of which are currently unavailable under the stripe umbrella.  The Stripe subscription code seems like a good quick win, but the long I work with it the more it chafes......